# Search a mysql database when using different combinations of filter selections

Tags: php, mysql, forms, search

I'm trying to search a mysql database when using different combinations of filter selections.

The example code for selecting which availability the products you search for should have is:

```
<select multiple="multiple" id="avail" class="avail" name="avail">
    <option selected="selected" value="0">All</option>
    <option value="1">Stock</option>
    <option value="3">Test</option>
    <option value="4">Special order</option>
</select>
```

If the option "All" was selected I would just not include it in the mysql query, but when I for example want to search for products that are "test" and "special order", and not "stock", what do I do then?

I believe the query would be something like:

```
SELECT * FROM products WHERE availability IN (an array)
```

But I dont know how to make an array from the selected values.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I'm using the phone app and I cant give you a full example, but use the php function implode to convert array to string and use your query, if you cant solve let me know and I'll write you and.example when I get home